# Error Spotting: Essay writing is an art (A) / that requires many planning (B) / on the part of the writer. (C)

Tags: exam-questions, error

I am an English language learner and was trying a to solve an error spotting set but I am not getting any error in the question below. There is a mistake in the statement classified into 3 parts (A, B & C).

Kindly help me detecting the error with explanation of rule behind that.

> Essay writing is an art (A) / that requires many planning (B) / on the part of the writer. (C) / No Error (D)

The answer set says there is an error in part B, but with no explanations.

Comment: I went ahead and reopened your question now that you've included more detail. Did you have an answer key for this question? I'm curious why you felt that "No Error" wasn't the correct option for this sentence.

Comment: Yes I have the answer set and it says there is an error in part B but with no explanations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Essay writing is an art (A) / **which** requires **much** planning (B) / on the part of the writer (C)

"**Planning**" is an uncountable noun, so use *much* as opposed to *many*.

Comment: Why did you switch "that" to "which"?

Comment: Yeah I have the same question...

Comment: My thinking in this case is "**that**" and "**which**" could be interchangeable, but , "**that**" only refers *specifically*  to "essay writing" whereas "**which**" implies more that "essay writing" is an art (one of many arts).